git push -u origin [branch] npm error Missing script: "version"
I am trying to push a new local branch into my remote version control. There is currently no remote branch. I have used the vs-code "Publish Branch" button and the command line git push -u origin [branch].
I'm using node v18.20.4 and npm  v10.7.0.
I get the following error:
git push -u origin [branch]
husky > pre-push (node v18.20.4)
npm error Missing script: "version"

How can I solve this error? The "version" command it's looking for doesn't seem like it should be defined in the package.json of my project, as none of the other repos I work with have it in their package.json.

It seems like you have some git hook (maybe via Husky?) trying to run a command, but without a [mre] there's not much we can do.

I copied the vs-code logs instead of the command line logs, so I hadn't noticed the additional context provided by it. It's complaining about husky > pre-push hook.

Then surely the script it's trying to call should be defined in that repo? It doesn't matter whether or not it's defined in the others, if nothing's looking for it there.
